# Using USB port data in PyQt

Tags: pyqt, port, pyserial, qmainwindow, pyqt6

The aim of my code is to create a window with labels, each representing a sensor. The data comes from the USB port in a table of 0s&1s and depending on the value it colours the labels accordingly.
The goal is supposed to look like this:

[image: this]

I am unsure of how to pass the data from the port to the function in real time without recreating the window as a whole each time, as I only want it to change the drawn labels (and their colours). Therefore, I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction or give me a suggestion of what I can do to make this work.

The code creating my main window & labels:

```
class MainWindow (qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.count = 0
        self.j = 0
        self.i = 0
        self.screen()
        self.making()

    def screen(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Bee Counter")
        self.showMaximized()

    def making(self):
        for i in values: #Iterates over the list of data which comes from the port.
            if (i == 1):
                self.label = qt.QLabel(self)
                self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: green; border: 1px solid black;")
                self.move_label() #Creates multiple labels with the colour green.
            else: 
                self.label = qt.QLabel(self)
                self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: red; border: 1px solid black;")
                self.move_label() #Creates multiple labels with the colour red.
            
            self.count +=1
            

    def move_label(self):
        self.label.resize(A, A)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        if self.count%2==0:
            k=20
            self.label.move(X0+self.j,k)
            self.j=self.j+X_STEP
            self.label.setText(f"{self.count}")

        else:
            k=90
            self.label.move(X0+self.i,k)
            self.label.setText(f"{self.count}")
            self.i=self.i+X_STEP
        self.label.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

The code getting the data from the port:

```
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM3',\
        baudrate=115200,\
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

    print("<Succesfully connected to: " + ser.portstr)

    while 1: 
        if ser.inWaiting()>0:
            line = ser.readline()
            line = line.decode('utf-8')
            line = [char for char in line if char=="1" or char=="0"] #Gets data in a form of a table of 0s & 1s.
            print(line)
            time.sleep(0.01) 

    ser.close()
```

P.S. Excuse my perhaps very obvious question, I simply can not wrap my head around it :)

Comment: [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue-objects) If you scroll down to the example; I was kind of thinking about making a painter that would do something like: `color = "red" if i else "green"` , `style = "background-color: {}; border: 1px solid black;"` and `label.setStyleSheet(style.format(color))`

Comment: My quick prototype, I took the serialport while loop and `def making(self):` and turned those into `def painter():` and `def initialize():`

Comment: @AnthonyL I see. Please correct me if I did not understand you right, but you suggest I use QPainter to create labels or simply just rename the function to painter? Also, I'm having difficulty understanding how things would work once I replace the serial port while loop, so is it perhaps possible to share an example? Sorry if my questions are unclear and thank you for helping regardless.

Comment: Not Qpainter, it's just a pythonic name for the desired action. Give me a few minutes here, never used PyQt before. If it's not like tkinter then I woulnd't bet on this running first time without errors, cause I don't have the package to run it

Comment: What is the "desired action"? Are you referring to the update of that "table"? Because any UI access can ***only*** happen in the main thread, and you cannot use blocking loops there.

Comment: @musicamante The desired action is to update the colour of the labels (or table) once the data, in the form of: [1,1,0,1,1,0,1], comes from the port.

Comment: And how frequently does the port send data?

Comment: @musicamante Approximately 25x a second.

Comment: @musicamante excellent insight explained wonderfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is based on the wrong premise: `making` should only create the labels (and keep a reference to them), while *another* function should be responsible for their update.

Since the data rate is quite fast and the display object very simple, it's probably better to use a custom widget instead of continuously set the style sheet.

```py
class DisplayWidget(QWidget):
    state = False
    def __init__(self, index):
        super().__init__()
        self.index = str(index)
        self.setFixedSize(32, 32)

    def setState(self, state):
        if self.state != state:
            self.state = state
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.green if self.state else Qt.red)
        qp.drawRect(self.rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))
        qp.drawText(self.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, self.index)
```

Now, the "viewer" is a custom widget that is able to create a predefined grid of display widgets and updates them when necessary.

You can provide a default field count, or just ignore that, since the function that updates the data is also capable to update the grid whenever the field count doesn't match.

```py
class SerialViewer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, fieldCount=None):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.widgets = []

        if isinstance(fieldCount, int) and fieldCount > 0:
            self.createGrid(fieldCount)

    def createGrid(self, fieldCount, rows=2):
        while self.widgets:
            self.widgets.pop(0).deleteLater()
        rows = max(1, rows)
        count = 0
        columns, rest = divmod(fieldCount, rows)
        if rest:
            columns += 1
        for column in range(columns):
            for row in range(rows):
                widget = DisplayWidget(count)
                self.layout().addWidget(widget, row, column)
                self.widgets.append(widget)
                count += 1
                if count == fieldCount:
                    break

    def updateData(self, data):
        if len(data) != len(self.widgets):
            self.createGrid(len(data))
        for widget, state in zip(self.widgets, data):
            widget.setState(state)
```

<sup>As you can see, instead of using `resize()` or `move()`, I'm using a [layout manager](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) that is automatically able to place (and eventually resize) the widgets. Remember, fixed geometries are almost always discouraged. Also note that widgets should not be directly added to a QMainWindow, but set for its *central widget*.</sup>

The thread is implemented in a QThread subclass, using a custom signal that is emitted whenever new data is available:

```py
class SerialThread(QThread):
    dataReceived = pyqtSignal(object)
    def run(self):
        ser = serial.Serial(
            port='COM3', 
            baudrate=115200, 
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

        self.keepRunning = True
        while self.keepRunning:
            if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                line = ser.readline()
                line = line.decode('utf-8')
                self.dataReceived.emit(
                    list(int(char) for char in line if char in '01')
                )

            # note that the indentation level of sleep() is *outside*
            # of the "if" otherwise it may temporarily block the loop
            # in case there is no data available
            time.sleep(0.01) 

    def stop(self):
        self.keepRunning = False
        self.wait()
```

Finally, the main window, from which we can start or stop the serial communication:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        self.startButton = QPushButton('Start')
        self.stopButton = QPushButton('Stop', enabled=False)

        self.serialViewer = SerialViewer(32)

        layout = QGridLayout(central)
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.stopButton, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.serialViewer, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        self.serialThread = SerialThread()

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.serialThread.stop)
        self.serialThread.dataReceived.connect(
            self.serialViewer.updateData)
        self.serialThread.finished.connect(self.stopped)

    def start(self):
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.serialThread.start()

    def stopped(self):
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)
```

Notes:

- Qt already provides an asynchronous class for serial communication that already supports signals, [QSerialPort](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html);
- the above codes use the old enum syntax, for Qt6 you need the full enum names (`Qt.GlobalColor.red`, `Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter`, etc);
- you will probably need a further check for the serial connection before starting the while loop in `run()`;

Comment: Oh wow, this works so perfectly, I clearly have so much to learn. Thank you from the bottom of my heart, is there a way I can buy you a coffee or something? :)

Comment: @wonderfuloceans You're very welcome! If you want to make a small donation, you can visit my profile page and follow the link :-)

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a way to handle repaint events with PyQt. I can't imagine there woulnd't be. I got carried away for a minute, but here is where I'm concluding my attempt. Hopefully this is of some help in anyway, I woulnd't expand on the queue. The main thread needs to come back to repaint it I think. The only issue is awaiting the serial's data, if there even is almost no wait time, I would expect it to hang, and leave the reciever flying through loops and burning up the CPU

```
import threading
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

def painter():
    while True: 
        if ser.inWaiting()>0:
            line = ser.readline()
            line = line.decode('utf-8')
            line = [char for char in line if char=="1" or char=="0"]
            print(line)
            time.sleep(0.01) 
    ser.close()


#stylesheet = "background-color: {}; border: 1px solid black;"
#color = "red" if i else "green"
#label.setStyleSheet(stylesheet.format(color))

class MainWindow (qt.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Bee Counter")
        self.showMaximized()

    def build_table(self, width=16, height=2):
        labels = [qt.QLabel(self) for _ in range(width*height)]
        for label in labels:
            label.setStyleSheet(style.format("red"))
        threading.Thread(target=painter).start()
```